# React native firebase auth().useEmulator is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to use the new firebase authentication emulator on React Native (0.63.3) on an android studio emulator (Pixel 4 API 29). In the newest major update of `react-native-firebase` (V 10.0.0), support for this was added, and I can see both the function and type definition in the `node-modules` package. But when I try and use the function, it simply isn't defined on the object. A lot of other functions are defined and work as expected (on production data), but not the `useEmulator` function. I've tried several ways of getting access to the object:

importing it directly:

```
import app from "@react-native-firebase/app";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
app.initializeApp(...);
console.log(auth().useEmulator);
```

importing the module like this:

```
import app from "@react-native-firebase/app"
import "@react-native-firebase/auth";
const auth = app.auth();
console.log(auth.useEmulator);
```

And they all log `undefined`. If I could get some tips on how to get this to work, it'd be greatly appreciated. Having access to the emulator while developing makes everything a little bit easier than having to make test users in the production data. The `functions.useEmulator` and `firestore.settings` works well and are defined, so there looks like there is something specific with the auth function.

My npm dependencies relating to this question:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.5.1",
"firebase": "^8.2.4",
```

My android firebase auth implementation version, if it is necessary:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2"
```